# apache camel! configure load balance to try on certain status codes

Tags: apache-camel

i have configured fail over load balancer below. the code reties on every error which it gets from server which i don't want. is there any way that load balancer retries on certain status codes say like 422

```
from("direct:a")
        .routeId("id123")
        .streamCaching()

        .loadBalance()
        .failover(3, false, true)
        .to("netty4:http:http://localhost:3000")
        .end()
```

i know we can do load balance on exceptions. but i want to do it on status codes.

can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, the failover load balancer works per exception.

You can set the netty4-http component to not throw exception on error, and then check the status code yourself and then throw an exception.

But its much easer to configure the `okStatusRange` option with the valid codes, then you only get exceptions for the invalid codes. See more at the docs at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-netty4-http/src/main/docs/netty4-http-component.adoc

Comment: from("direct:a")
        .routeId("id123")
        .streamCaching()

        .loadBalance()
        .failover(3, false, true)
        .to("netty4:http:http://localhost:3000").process(exchange -> {
          System.out.println(Instant.now() +"|"+exchange.getIn().getHeaders().get("CamelHttpResponseCode"));
        })
        .end() i am not getting response code for all requests.. am i doing anything wrong